# How can a session variable equality check have a different result only in Safari?

Tags: php, safari, cross-browser, session-variables

I have a function as follows:

```
function checkKey($key, $instance, $use = true) {

    $validKey = false;

    if ($key == $_SESSION[$instance]) {
        $validKey = true;
        if ($use) {
            unset($_SESSION[$instance]);
        }
    }

    return $validKey;
}
```

This is working exactly as expected when called in e.g. Chrome and Firefox, but always returning false in Safari.

Are there any known issues regarding Safari handling session variables in a different way than other browsers? Is there anything obvious I could be doing to get around Safari not cooperating with the above code?

ETA: Maybe I can clarify this further. I have a collection of links, each of which should be able to download a file once. When the links are generated, a key is created, included in the querystring of the link, and set as a session variable. When the link is used, the key is checked, either the file or a 404 is given, and the session variable in unset. As stated, this works as desired in Chrome, but fails every time in Safari... surely there must be something about trying to do this kind of thing that Safari doesn't like?

Comment: Is the session actually working in Safari, can you do a `var_dump()` or check the cookies?

Comment: Sessions depend on cookies. Do you have cookies disabled in Safari?

Comment: Is this a frame-based website?

Comment: safari has absolutely nothing to do with session variables. the **ONLY** thing that safari has that relates to the session is the session ID in a cookie. If the cookie isn't working properly, you'll just get a different/empty session instead.

Comment: Cookies not disabled, iframes are involved on the site but it seems like this breaks even when when they aren't, var_dump does seem to show that $_SESSION[$instance] is NULL in Safari just before the equality check. So presumably there's nothing wrong with the above simple code, but it's still difficult to see why things are working differently only in Safari. *scratches head*

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but I would strongly consider using `===` rather than `==` for a stricter equality check.

Comment: That's sound advice @eluong... though of course in this case I'm desperate for the check to succeed, not to be harder to satisfy! (A poor excuse I know...)